# Multiple Background Processes at Single Line Works in The Foreground

Tags: linux, php, imagemagick, background-process, exec

I want to convert an uploaded PDF file to JPG images and zip these images after convert process finishes. I use the `ImageMagick` library's `convert` command for PDF to JPG conversion.

To accomplish this, I use the `&&` operand like this:

```
convert /tmp/asdassa_1395994117.pdf -density 200 /tmp/files/asdassa_1395994117.pdf.jpg && zip -r /tmp/files/files.zip /tmp/files/* &
```

This command works just fine except one thing: It runs on the foreground so the server doesn't respond until it finishes.

If I use either one of these commands by adding `&` at the end of the command, it runs on the background and I can get the response asap. But when using together, it doesn't.

Is there something that I'm missing? Might it be about the command type? Because testing the `&&` and `&` operands with simple commands like `sleep` and `mkdir` works on the background as I expect to be, for example this command:

```
sleep 10 && mkdir bla &
```

Goes to the background and creates the bla dir after 10 seconds.

P.S. My server runs on Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03

Edit: It turned out that the problem wasn't about the OS but the `exec()` function of PHP. Please check my answer to see how I worked it out.

Comment: Given the examples provided, I cannot duplicate the problem behaviour.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Okay, one more detail. I'm using PHP's exec() function. Do you think it will matter?

Comment: Yes, yes, we do.  And congratulations on figuring it out (seriously, +1 for that).  But **please** consider this a learning experience in writing a good question: don't **tell** us what you think are the important bits of what you're doing, **show** us in as much detail as possible.  Otherwise, you may well miss out the key element, the one that leads to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So it turned out that the problem wasn't about how I was using the commands but how I was using the commands from PHP.

I was doing it like this:

```
exec($command);
```

However, I then found out that the `exec()` command doesn't like these kind of usage. So instead of passing the command directly, I decided to put the command to a temporary `.sh` file and use it in `exec()` instead.

```
// create the command, don't forget to delete the temporary file with a last command
$command = "convert /tmp/asdassa_1395994117.pdf -density 200 /tmp/files/asdassa_1395994117.pdf.jpg && zip -r /tmp/files/files.zip /tmp/files/* && rm /tmp/temp.sh";

// create file with this command
exec("echo '".$command."' > /tmp/temp.sh");

// execute on the background with output
exec("sh /tmp/temp.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
```

This works well.